# assume statement modelling in FramaC

Tags: frama-c

I want to use user assertion of **value analysis** plugin of Frama-C (Neon version), however I have some problem to come up with the suitable model of `assume` statement, which is very useful for me to apply particular constraints, for example, here is my test code:

```html
#include "/usr/local/share/frama-c/builtin.h"

int main(void)
{
    int selection = Frama_C_interval(0,10);
    int a;
    assume(selection > 5);
    if (selection > 5)
    {
        a = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        a = 1;
    }
    //@ assert a == 2;
    return 0;
}
```

I want that the value of `selection` will be greater than 5 after this `assume` statement so that the assertion will be valid.
My initial attempt was to write this function
`void assume(int a){ while(!a); return;}`
, but it was unsuccessful.
Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Maybe you would be interested in http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2012/08/03/assume-and-assert , which argues that “assume” and “assert” should both be the same construct (“assert”) in a multi-technique framework such as Frama-C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to constrain `selection` would be to use an `assert` (which of course won't be proved by Value). If you want to distinguish between the `assert` that are in fact hypotheses you make from the `assert` that you want to verify, you can use ACSL's naming mechanism, such as

```
//@ assert assumption: selection > 5;
```

and verify that the only `assert` that are unknown are the ones named `assumption`.

Using an `assume` function cannot work as such, because it will only reduce the possible value of the `a` parameter to be non-zero. Value is not able to infer the relation between the value of `a` in `assume` and the value of `selection` in `main`. However, it is possible to help it a little bit. First, `-slevel` allows to propagate several abstract state in parallel. Second, an `assert` given in an disjunctive will force Value to split its state (if the `-slevel` is big enough to do so). Thus, with the following code

```
#include "builtin.h"

void assume(int a) { while(!a); return; }

int main(void)
{
     int selection = Frama_C_interval(0,10);
     int a;
     /*@ assert selection > 5 || selection <= 5; */
     assume(selection > 5);
    if (selection > 5)
    {
        a = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        a = 1;
    }
    //@ assert a == 2;
    return 0;
}
```

and the following command line:

```
frama-c -cpp-extra-args="-I$(frama-c -print-share-path)" -val -slevel 2
```

After the first `assert` (which obviously valid), Frama-C will propagate separately two states: one in which `selection > 5` and one in which `selection <= 5`. In the first case, `assume` is called with `1` as argument, thus returns immediately, and the `then` branch of the `if` is taken, so that the second `assert` is valid. In the second state, `assume` is called with `0`, and never returns. Thus for all cases where control reaches the second `assert`, it is valid.

Note that you really need to add the first `assert` inside the body of `main`, and to copy in ACSL the argument you pass to `assume`. Otherwise, the state split won't occur (more precisely, you will split on `a`, not on `selection`).

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer.

Comment: Following your answer, is it correct if I model `assume(cond)` as `//@ assert cond || !cond; assume(cond)` for all the assume statements ? ( with `cond` in assert in ACSL and sufficient large`-slevel`). Are there any exceptions? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Yes, this should work, provided `cond` is something Value Analysis can handle (i.e. something like `x<=42`, `*p>36`, `p <= &x + 12`, ... the latter possibly leading to an alarm if `p` is too imprecise and can have several base addresses).